# Why is my instance_variable nil? (2 lines of code)

Tags: ruby, instance-variables, monkeypatching

I'm trying to create a hash which stores an auto-increment number for a non-existent key.
I'm aware there are other, less brittle, ways to do this; my question is : why does my instance variable fail so miserably?

```
h = Hash.new{|h,k| h[k] = (@max_value += 1)}
h.instance_variable_set(:@max_value, 0) # zero ! Not nil! Argh...

puts h[:a]  # expecting 1; getting NoMethodError undefined method '+' for nil:NilClass
puts h[:b]  # expecting 2
puts h[:a]  # expecting 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not doing what you think you're doing.

When you call Hash.new, you're referencing @max_value *as it exists right now in the current scope*. The current scope is the top level, it's not defined there, so you get nil.

You then set an instance variable on the instance that happens to be called @max_value as well, but it's not the same thing.

You probably want something like...well, actually, I can't imagine a situation where this mechanism is a good solution to anything, but it's what you asked for so lets run with it.

```
h = Hash.new{|h,k| h[k] = (h.instance_variable_set(:@max_value,    
                               h.instance_variable_get(:@max_value) + 1))}

h.instance_variable_set :@max_value, 0

puts h[1]  #=> 1
puts h[10] #=> 2
```

Note that I'm explicitly getting/setting the instance variable associated with `h in all cases. More verbose, but what you need.